# Canonical commutation relation on the spatial boundary of the hypersurface

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator, boundary-conditions, poisson-brackets, canonical-conjugation

Consider the equal time commutation relation of a field given on a $d$ dimensional spacelike hypersurface $\Sigma$ of a $d+1$ dimensional manifold given by

$$[\Pi(t, x), \Phi(t, x')] = i\hbar\delta^{(d)}(x-x')\tag{1}$$

What will this commutation relation look like on the spatial boundary? Will it be $$\big[[\Pi](t, y), [\Phi]\big(t, y')] \propto i\hbar\delta^{(d-1)}(y-y')\tag{2}$$

where $$[A] \equiv A\big|_{\partial\Sigma}\tag{3}$$ and $y$ is the coordinate on $\partial\Sigma$?

Comment: Do you mean a QFT on a spatial manifold with boundary? What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov How about $\Phi |_{\partial\Sigma} = \phi_0$ where $\phi_0$ is some arbitrary function?

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): Eqs. (1)-(3) are dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: @Dr.user44690 if you're fixing the value of the field at the boundary, it can't possibly have nontrivial commutation relations with anything. In fact the quantization will just be a multiple of the identity operator.